# Apache doesn't look at httpd.conf on mac

Tags: mac, apache-http-server

I use apache on my MacBook to test SSL with my rails applications, turned it on today and its not working. I just get "Safari can’t connect to the server." for any https requests and I can't work out why. Its acting like apache isnt running but as far as I can tell it is.

I have something else running on port 80 which is working fine, its just https on port 443 that isnt (aka just apache) I now believe that its not picking up on my config in httpd.conf because I added "this wont work" to the end of httpd.conf expecting to see errors on startup but none appeared.

Has there been an update or some config change which will stop apache from loading my config file?

Comment: By any chance are you running Skype? I know on the PC version at least it uses ports 80 and 443 when it cannot route using its standard methods. Check the Skype preferences and disable this feature if it is enabled.

Comment: I do use skype, but its not in start up so would only interfere when it was open?

Comment: I'm not sure what the case is with the OS X version, whether it registers a service that runs in the background or not. I think with this particular question however, you might find an answer more quickly in a more appropriate forum.

Comment: possibly, but that still wouldn't cause apache to ignore httpd.conf or would cause apache to error saying socket already in use when i started it.

Comment: In that case, I'm not certain off hand, I would suggest asking in a forum more suited to webmaster tasks in this instance however.